# Create List from Elements of Tuples with Exclusion

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to make a list of items from the elements of tuples in a list such that those elements don't belong to some other list, and I know that each tuple contains one element from the list I don't want it to belong to and one element that's not in that list. For example, with

```
tuples = [(2,1), (1,4), (1,7), (3,10), (4,3)]
exclude = [1, 3]
```

I am looking to create the list

```
[2, 4, 7, 10]
```

This is easy enough to accomplish in a clumsy for loop, but it seems like there's a more pythonic way using some function or list comprehension. Any ideas?

Comment: The rule that you exclude elements is not clear. Shouldn't your resulting list contain 3 elements, not 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't actually understand the question. Assuming this may be you want

```
>>>list(set([j for i in tuples for j in i if not j in exclude]))
[2, 4, 10, 7]
```

Comment: Well, seems I was too late :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a 4 in your example, the code will return :

```
>>>[num for tup in tuples for num in tup if num not in exclude]
[2, 4, 7, 10, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your requirement is to convert list of tuples to a list and then getting unique elements in the list, exclusing the list exclude and then sorting them.

```
from itertools import chain
tuples_final = sorted(list(set(chain(*tuples))-set(exclude)))
```